# Angular 13 - Cannot use namespace as a type.ts(2709)

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-components, ngrx-store

Am working on angular 13 version.Trying to import and use action file inside a `.spec` file shows  an error like below

```
Cannot use namespace 'MyActions' as a type.ts(2709)
```

This is my spec file

```
import * as MyActions from '../../core/store/action/my.actions';
describe('MyActionComponent', () => {
  let myActions: MyActions;
```

Please excuse for full source code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: MyAction is a namespace and not a type. Use an exporting interface of the namespace like `let myActions: MyAction.SomeActionType`

Comment: @Deitsch it showing some other issue

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: @Deitsch MyActions.loadMyActionSuccess' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof  MyActions.loadMyActionSuccess'?ts(2749)

Comment: If you want to assign a value use the `=` operator. `:` is used for specifying a type. Also please edit your question and add the `MyActions` namespace so we can discuss this better.

Answer (score 0):

MyAction is a namespace and not a type, hence the error.
You object can only be of type coming from said namespace (or any other namespace). You may want to use an exporting interface of the namespace:

```js
import * as MyActions from '../../core/store/action/my.actions';

describe('MyActionComponent', () => {
    let myActions: MyAction.SomeInterface
    ...
});
```